# C# dynamic logic gate

Tags: c#

I am working on a program that would allow the user to build digital circuits from virtual logic gates. Every gate would be an instance of a class that represents particular gate type, for example here's how AND class looks:

```
public class andgate
{
    public andgate()
    {
        inputs = new bool[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) inputs[i] = true;
        output = (inputs[0] && inputs[1] && inputs[2] && inputs[3] && inputs[4] && inputs[5] && inputs[6]);
    }
    public bool[] inputs;
    public bool output;
}
```

Every gate has seven inputs but not all of them have to be used (i.e. for a gate with three imputs the remaining four will just be "1" which is AND's neutral element anyway). Each input is a reference to an output of another gate or to an element of bool array (which stores the input vector) so that signal generated by one gate automatically is sent to the following gate. The problem is I also need the signal to be transmitted dynamically within the gate, i.e. if one of the input signals in AND gate is set to 0 then the output automatically has a 0 value. Therefore when you feed a binary vector to the inputs of the cirtuit, it changes the values of the circuit's outputs. Or maybe there's an easier way to simulate a circuit than building it from individual gates? I need it for test pattern generating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `output` property read-only:

```
public bool output
{
    get
    {
        return inputs.All(i => i);
    }
}
```

Instead of ANDing all the inputs, just check if there is any input that is false.

Of course you have to remove the assignment to `output` in the constructor. This should make your `output` property "dynamic".

You may also want to change the inputs to `bool?[]` instead, so that a `null` value would signify that there is no signal. You will then have to remove the initialization of the input array to all true and change the output return to:

```
return inputs.All(i => i.GetValueOrDefault(true));
```

Edited with Tim S's suggestions in the comments

Comment: `!inputs.Any(i => !i)`? Hard to read. `inputs.All(i => i)`. Easy to read (IMO), same effect. And for `bool?`, `inputs.All(i => i == true)`.  Just because the code *works*, doesn't mean it's *good*.

Comment: First, nowhere in my answer did I say that my answer is *good*. My coding prowess is not as good as I would like it to be for me to say that my answer is emphatically *good*. I simply proposed a solution to his problem, and made a suggestion which I can say is better than his current implementation. Second, wouldn't an Any() be faster, though? I'm not sure about that. Third,  wouldn't your code suggestion for `bool?` = false if any of the inputs are null?

Comment: Any is more efficient and bool? does not evaluate to false when it is null.

Comment: `Any` and `All` are the same speed (they can each short-circuit to avoid iterating the whole list, just like `&&` and `||` do).  Yes, you're right about my `bool?` code.  I wasn't sure of the desired behavior, but it's much easier to read and write what's going on in that form.  Maybe `i != false` (or, equivalently, `i.GetValueOrDefault(true)`) is what you're looking for: `true` and `null` are considered the same and can result in `true`, while a single `false` results in `false`.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use a properties to set/get the inputs, as you can perform additional computations in a property. The state variables you're holding should be private.

```
public bool[] Inputs {
    set {
        inputs = value;
    }
}

public bool Output {
    get {
        return inputs[0] && inputs[1] ...
    }
}
```

I would avoid doing this for the Inputs property, since exposing arrays is really exposing information about how the class stores things, which should be avoided where possible for good OOP. A ReadOnlyCollection might be more suitable, for example.

However, I would rethink the design in general, and avoid having some arbitrary # of inputs, 7. Where have you conjured that value from?

A more simplistic approach would be to assume that a gate takes 2 values - A and B, for which you can set the values in the constructor or individual properties.

You then take advantage of the fact that operations on binary logic gates are associative, so an AND gate taking a, b, c, is equivalent to one taking a, b, feeding it's output to another which also takes c. This is how you'd build a circuit in practice anyway - the issue you need to consider is the latency of the gate though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should add events into your gates, such that when their state changes they're able to notify dependant objects; something like this:

```
public class AndGate
{

    private bool[] inputs;
    private bool output;

    public bool[] Inputs 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.inputs;
        }
        set
        {
            this.inputs = value; 
            UpdateOutput();     
        }
    }
    public bool Output
    {
        get
        {
            return this.output;
        }
    }

    public AndGate()
    {
        inputs = new bool[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) inputs[i] = true;
        UpdateOutput();
    }

    private void UpdateOutput()
    {
        bool original = output;
        output = true;
        for(int i=0; i<inputs.Length; i++)
        {
            output = output && inputs[i];
        }
        if (original != output)
        {
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event GateStateChangedEventHandler StateChanged;  
    protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (StateChanged != null) 
        {
            StateChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ps. the class should also contain listeners for each of the inputs connected to other gates / changeable sources so it can react to changes in other gates as well as triggering them.